# FFmpeg Optimized File Size Video Loop

Tags: ffmpeg, video, audio, encoding, memory

I am attempting to create a video loop by merging a 15 second video with about 4 minutes of audio. After finding a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015771/merge-video-and-audio-with-ffmpeg-loop-the-video-while-audio-is-not-over/55841289#55841289), I found a command that loops the input video for the length of the audio, and results in a merged video file that plays like I intended.

`ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i loop.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -shortest -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c copy output.mp4`

While the resulting video plays as I wanted, I noticed that the file size is much larger than I expected. I presume I am not understanding what the *-stream_loop* option is actually doing. In my case, I input a 45Mb video clip and a 6Mb audio clip, yet the resulting video is about 690Mb. The video loop repeats about 15 times before the audio is done. Since 45Mb * 15 + 6Mb is about 680Mb, it looks like *-stream_loop* is not instancing the clip, and is just repeating the memory. I expected a file size not much larger than the sum of the input files' sizes, just over 50Mb.

I found several other questions and answers regarding merging a video loop with an audio track, but I didn't find anyone commenting about the resulting file size. Admittedly, I am a beginner with this process, but my expectation was the default behavior for a command that creates a loop from an input source would be to efficiently instance it whenever possible.

1. Is the *-stream_loop* option actually repeating the input video clip frames to make the loop?
2. Is there a way to tell ffmpeg to instance the input video frames when creating the loop?
3. Is this actually a limitation with video formats (e.g. mp4, mkv, etc.)?
4. If ffmpeg is not sufficient for this, is there some way to create a video that efficiently (with respect to file size) loops the video clip for the duration of an audio clip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the -stream_loop option actually repeating the input video clip frames to make the loop?

Yes.

> Is there a way to tell ffmpeg to instance the input video frames when creating the loop?

No.

> Is this actually a limitation with video formats (e.g. mp4, mkv, etc.)?

For MP4s and MKVs, yes.

> If ffmpeg is not sufficient for this, is there some way to create a video that efficiently (with respect to file size) loops the video clip for the duration of an audio clip?

Not that I know of. Some vendors like Whatsapp have customized MP4s to allow this. However, the player has to recognize and implement the proprietary loop instruction.

Comment: In theory, one can use custom edit lists in MP4s to implement this in a backward compatible way, but I don't know of a tool that does so.